# How to implement mouse events in VPython correctly(invalid syntax error)?

Tags: python, mouseevent, vpython

I try to drag objects with the mouse. So when I let them go with the mouse, they have the new position of the mouse. I have two problems. 1. In Glowscript it runs but there is no action let go the mouse. When I click it I can drag it. But when I want to let go the mouse it continues dragging the object until I shut the program . 2. I can't run it in a Python editor, bc I get the error invalid syntax for this line: `scene.bind("mousedown", def():`

Whole code:

```
drag=False
R = vec(0,0,0)
scene.bind("mousedown", def():
    global drag
    drag=True

    scende.bind("mouseup", def():
        global drag
        drag=False
    )
)

while (True):

    rate(framerate)  
    if drag:
        R=scene.mouse.pos
        e.pos=R
    if running
```

Of course there are thing missing in this code. Above it I generate the constants and objects and under `if running` the functions are. This is the code for the drag event where the mistake has to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
drag=False
R = vec(0,0,0)
scene.bind("mousedown", def():
    global drag
    drag=True

    scene.bind("mouseup", def():
        global drag
        drag=False
    )
)

while (True):

    rate(framerate)  
    if drag:
        R=scene.mouse.pos
        e.pos=R
    if running
```